# Implement Comet Programming

Tags: web-applications, comet, cometd, cometserver

I am new to comet programming.

I browsed for information on how to achieve this, I found that it can be done through LightStreamer. But when I tried to implement that, I felt few libraries missing.

Recently I read an article from http://cometdaily.com/maturity.html, here it stated few transports that are not supported. Currently I know JS and AJAX. I want to know a framework or technology that helps me achieve this.

I need to get data from the server whenever there is any change as well as other clients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to look at [CometD](http://cometd.org), that provides a [reference documentation](http://docs.cometd.org/reference), [tutorials](http://docs.cometd.org/tutorials) that help you getting started with CometD programming and ships with a [distribution](http://download.cometd.org) that contains many examples.